# How to use InvokePattern on Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the InvokePattern method in Xamarin Android in order to change the pattern of a polyline. The method definition is the following:

```
public PolylineOptions InvokePattern(IList<PatternItem> pattern);
```

I have tried doing this:

```
var polyline = new PolylineOptions();
polyline.InvokePattern(new PatternItem());
```

But it doesn't work. How can I set the pattern to, for example, "Gap"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. The following code works for me:

```
var list = new List<PatternItem>();
list.Add(new PatternItem(1, Java.Lang.Float.ValueOf(2)));
polylineOptions.InvokePattern(list);
```

You can change the pattern from the PatternItem's first overload. 0 is default (straight line) and 1 is a pointed line. The second overload is the size of the gaps